# Create a common builder for an object irrespective of fields being passed in

Tags: java, java-8, builder

I'have a class which has multiple fields:

```
@Builder
public class SampleClass {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;
}
```

I've a helper class which does some string modification:

```
public class StringModifier {
    public static String prefixUnderscore(String text) {
        return "_" + text;
    }

    public static String postfixUnderscore(String text) {
        return text + "_";
    }
}
```

Now based on some conditions, I may have either field a or field b. To build the object I do:

```
private static SampleClass getSampleClassWithB(String b, String c, Function<String, String> mapper) {
        String d = mapper.apply(b);
        return SampleClass.builder().b(b).c(c).d(d).build();
    }

    private static SampleClass getSampleClassWithA(String a, String c, Function<String, String> mapper) {
        String d = mapper.apply(a);
        return SampleClass.builder().a(a).c(c).d(d).build();
    }
```

And to use these functions:

```
getSampleClassWithA("a", "c", StringModifier::postfixUnderscore);
getSampleClassWithB("b", "c", StringModifier::prefixUnderscore);
```

Now as you can see both getSampleClassWithA & getSampleClassWithB do pretty similar things. Is there a way to combine this into a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, if two or more methods are doing mostly the same and you want to avoid the code duplication, you have to find an abstraction for the difference, in this case, the invocation of either, `a` or `b`, on the builder:

```
private static SampleClass getSampleClassWith(
    String value, BiFunction<SampleClassBuilder,String,SampleClassBuilder> property,
    String c, Function<String, String> mapper) {

    return property.apply(SampleClass.builder(),value).c(c).d(mapper.apply(value)).build();
}
```

```
getSampleClassWith("a", SampleClassBuilder::a, "c", StringModifier::postfixUnderscore);
getSampleClassWith("b", SampleClassBuilder::b, "c", StringModifier::prefixUnderscore);
```

Comment: Could you explain the order in which the BiFunction works? How does property.apply actually create the builder and then apply property a or b

Comment: The builder still is created via `SampleClass.builder()` which is passed as argument to the `apply` method. In this context, `SampleClassBuilder::a` is equivalent to `(builder,arg) -> builder.a(arg)`. Since the caller passes the result of `SampleClass.builder()` and the function returns the result of `a(…)`, the result is the same as with the `SampleClass.builder().a(…) …` chain.